# Python: Extracting float values from array of lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

during data processing I create an array looking like this:

```
[array([ 0.08606408]) array([ 0.26071976])
 array([ 0.181566  ,  0.94154611]) array([ 0.1734347 ,  0.94160601])
 array([ 0.17859844,  0.94167483]) array([ 0.16880761,  0.94156277])
 array([ 0.17624151,  0.94149038]) array([ 0.18770433,  0.94181287])
 array([ 0.16707977,  0.94227733]) array([ 0.94162233])
 array([ 0.9426902,  0.9615621]) array([ 0.94195127,  0.96174422])
 array([ 0.94237795,  0.96195226,  0.98059446])
 array([ 0.94249657,  0.96219391,  0.98095329])
 array([ 0.94280697,  0.96286183,  0.98109352])
 array([ 0.94267473,  0.96304417,  0.98252799])]
```

created in the following manner:

```
peakpositions = []
peakpositions.append(stuff)
```

How do I extract the float values into a single 1D numpy array?
What I want is this:

```
[0.08606408, 0.26071976, 0.181566 ... 0.98252799]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `np.concatenate(peakpositions)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate your inner arrays :

```
peakpositions=np.concatenate(peakpositions)
```

Demo :

```
>>> l= [[array([ 0.08606408]), array([ 0.26071976]),
       array([ 0.181566  ,  0.94154611]),
       array([ 0.1734347 ,  0.94160601]),
       array([ 0.17859844,  0.94167483]),
       array([ 0.16880761,  0.94156277]),
       array([ 0.17624151,  0.94149038]),
       array([ 0.18770433,  0.94181287]),
       array([ 0.16707977,  0.94227733]), array([ 0.94162233]),
       array([ 0.9426902,  0.9615621]), array([ 0.94195127,  0.96174422]),
       array([ 0.94237795,  0.96195226,  0.98059446]),
       array([ 0.94249657,  0.96219391,  0.98095329]),
       array([ 0.94280697,  0.96286183,  0.98109352]),
       array([ 0.94267473,  0.96304417,  0.98252799])]
>>> np.concatenate(l)
array([ 0.08606408,  0.26071976,  0.181566  ,  0.94154611,  0.1734347 ,
        0.94160601,  0.17859844,  0.94167483,  0.16880761,  0.94156277,
        0.17624151,  0.94149038,  0.18770433,  0.94181287,  0.16707977,
        0.94227733,  0.94162233,  0.9426902 ,  0.9615621 ,  0.94195127,
        0.96174422,  0.94237795,  0.96195226,  0.98059446,  0.94249657,
        0.96219391,  0.98095329,  0.94280697,  0.96286183,  0.98109352,
        0.94267473,  0.96304417,  0.98252799])
>>>
```

Comment: For the first option, you need to convert `peakpositions` to `numpy.array` before: `numpy.array(peakpositions).flatten()`.

Comment: Actually, the first one does not work (at least with my version of `numpy` and `python`) because `numpy` is able to flatten a 2d `numpy.array` but not a `numpy.array` of `numpy.array`. Anyway, I though the second method would be really slow but it runs in less than `.3s` on my (poor) computer with a list of `1000000` arrays of random size (between `1` and `10`).

Comment: @Holt Yeah `flatten` doesn't works on this case sine it is a list contain numpy arrays!

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list/array and extend it.

```
array_1d = []
for array in arrays:
    array_1d.extend(array)
```

That should do the magic.